# How to schedule a parameterized Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibrach Jenkins pipeline job which accepts some parameters from users following 'Build with parameters' option.
Now, I need to schedule this job to run on the monthly basis. Since, the job can't be completed with user inputs. Is there a way to schedule and run this kind of job? I was wondering that the job can be triggered automatically but it might keep waiting for the user inputs. Can I use any alerting mechanism?

Comment: You can use 'Parameterized Scheduler Plugin' . After installing it you can provide default parameters to run this job automatically. In job configuration there is Build Triggers sections,which allows you to set up schedule and parameters for the job to run. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported for multibrach pipeline.

Comment: Add it to your jenkins script. Something like:  properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('0 0 1 * *')])]). You can lookup other options here: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Finally got it working the way I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the configuration of multibranch pipeline and navigate to the Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers and schedule the job accordingly. ( **As shown below** )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of 'paremeterized-schedular-plugin' to schedule any parameterized Jenkins job. Parameterized cron can also be defined in declarative pipeline.
Reference:
 https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md